# Schema rails file showing non existing column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, schema

I have a strange problem with my schema file. Recently I accidently saw that there is a column in one table, that doesn't exist in a database. It looks like this

im mysql console

[image]

in rails console

[image]

so clearly there 6 columns besides the id column. but now in my db/schema file there is also a 'phone' column.

[image]

How is it possible? And how to delete this column from schema file??

Comment: Do you have a migration that adds a phone column to any other table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might fix your `schema.rb` file:

```
$ rake db:schema:dump
```